# IP Address Mismatch on signing into Heroku CLI

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

Previously I could sign into the heroku command line interface with `heroku login`. But now I get an [IP address mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Cau.png) error. How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Copy and paste `heroku login -i` in your terminal. This is what solved it for me.

Comment: This is no longer the case when you have "authorization token" attached to your account!

Comment: Error: Your account has MFA enabled; API requests using basic authentication with email and password are not
 »   supported. Please generate an authorization token for API access.

Comment: This works for me but instead of setting your usual password, you should use the generated token available on your account.

Comment: This won't work with macOS 12 and later. You'll need to temporarily turn off Private Relay

Comment: Interestingly ... I ran this (and it failed because I have MFA enabled), but afterwards `heroku login` worked (I kept getting `IP address mismatch` after logging in via browser before).

Answer (score 48):

Just adding some detailed steps to resolve the issue

1. Navigate to https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/applications
2. In Authorizations click on create authorization button
3. Add description in pop up eg.heroku cli and leave expire after blank if you dont want it to expire
4. You will get authorization token
5. in cli run heroku login -i
6. when it prompts for password enter the authoriation token

Comment: This is what worked for me

Comment: This is the way to do it if you use authorization tokens.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer (run `heroku login -i`) doesn't work for accounts with MFA enabled. What I did instead was to reveal my account's API key and put it into `~/.netrc` like so:

```
machine api.heroku.com
  login <MY_EMAIL>
  password <API_KEY>
machine git.heroku.com
  login <MY_EMAIL>
  password <API_KEY>
```

And *voila*! I can now use the CLI. This worked for me with Google CloudShell.

P.S. -- I added my machine's SSH key but could not understand how to use that to configure the CLI's access. It seems hard-coded to look for API keys in `~/.netrc`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Multi-Factor Authentication you could generate an Authorization token in settings page: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/applications

Run `heroku login -i` and use the generated token as password.

Comment: works for me - annoying though

Comment: I tried many of the suggested solutions on here.This is the first one that worked for me. Tanks!

Answer (score 7):

For accounts that have MFA.

Run heroku login, press any key to open up browser window. Copy the url and open it in incognito mode.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a Mac running macOS 12 Monterey with the Private Relay feature enabled, you'll need to turn that off while you complete the Heroku CLI authentication workflow, since that feature is obfuscating your actual IP address by proxying your traffic through a pool of IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you. This explains why it is just started happening, seemingly out of nowhere; but it had been a week or more since I enabled Private Relay. But `heroku login -i` worked.

Answer (score 4):

This error will occur when your machine is behind a proxy if you disable the proxy temporarily then authentication will be done.

Comment: this was the only  answer that helped me. thx!

Comment: This worked. I had a  local DNS server running, I stopped for a few seconds and it was able to log in.

Answer (score 3):

for me **heroku login -i** worked..
didnt need the token.after **heroku login -i** it wanted my credentials...i.e email and password and i was logged in

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Multi Factor Authentication you have to create an API key. To do that:

1. Go here: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account (login if asked)
2. Click here:
   [image]
3. Open the hidden file located at ~/.netrc and paste your API key in the two 'password' fields.
   For example, if your API key is 'a8g73nga-9vb2-0184-afbc-54fac2b66c75', then it should look like this:

```
machine api.heroku.com
  login your.email@example.com
  password a8g73nga-9vb2-0184-afbc-54fac2b66c75
machine git.heroku.com
  login your.email@example.com
  password a8g73nga-9vb2-0184-afbc-54fac2b66c75
```

4. The heroku CLI will now work!

#### Reference

- Heroku CLI Authentication [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication)

Answer (score 2):

New changes where added by Heroku on login. You can find the change logs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy).

In case if you are behind the firewall you may need to set the proxy.

> set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber

Comment: what does portnumber refer to, and what should it be set to?  

are `proxy` or `server` also meant to be place holders for some other value, or should they be interpreted literally?

Comment: Probably due to this issue, I found that as a workaround I could just turn on a VPN, redo the login and everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a Mac user on 12.3 or later, you need to open System Preferences, > Network > Wi-Fi, and then uncheck "Limit IP Address Tracking" for the duration of your authentication.

New OSX masks your IP address, and Heroku login doesn't know how to deal with it. All you need is to let Heroku verify IP before/after auth, and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
1/ Logout in the browser
2/ Clear cache and cookies for heroku.com (optional)
3/ Run "heroku login"
4/ Logging in the browser tab opened by the CLI

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Close or switch terminal, and then rerun the command "heroku login" This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I initially installed Heroku with Snap software package manager.
Installing it with npm solved my problem.
copy and paste the code below.

```
npm i -g heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

My default browser is Safari with private relay on. This was my issue. I just copied the url from the Safari browser to one of my other browsers (Brave) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect with the following:
heroku login -I //
email: user@email.com //
password: api key # from account settings

So satisfying!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `heroku login -i` led to some I/O issues on Google Colab for me.

I needed to press the `return` key multiple times after entering the password, and that somehow made the credentials incorrect.

I had to open up a Colab Terminal to login as I would via any Linux-based shell (The Colab terminal is available on Colab Pro and Pro+).

Answer (score 0):

Turning on a VPN solved it for me. It's possible the incognito browser or clearing cookies would work, too.

The issue is that my browser and CLI had different IP addresses: [https://help.heroku.com/CBF0T4AJ/can-t-login-to-heroku-using-cli-getting-ip-address-mismatch#:~:text=This%20means%20that%20you%20will,the%20changes%20to%20take%20effect](https://help.heroku.com/CBF0T4AJ/can-t-login-to-heroku-using-cli-getting-ip-address-mismatch#:%7E:text=This%20means%20that%20you%20will,the%20changes%20to%20take%20effect).

Heroku's suggestion is to set up a server proxy, but the VPN is effectively proxying all the traffic anyway, so that works.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for next time.

1. login in heroku in browser
2. generate and open link again

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the Solutions mentioned above but the VPN solved my issue.
I think i have a problem with my ISP or HTTP PROXY

> HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.server.com:portnumber

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30444778)