# IP Address Mismatch when trying to access Heroku CLI

Tags: heroku

It is my first app that I am deploying to heroku but I am stuck on this error and do not know how to go about it. I've tried `heroku login-i` , this doesn't work for me because I have MFA activated.

Comment: In my case, I was using PowerShell to log in and switched to git bash, which worked great. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363085/ip-address-mismatch-on-signing-into-heroku-cli answers for more solutions others have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following step to resolve the IP mismatch issue:

- Navigate to https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/applications
- Click on create authorization button in the Authorizations tab.
- Add a description and leave expire as blank.
- Copy the Authorization token.
- Open terminal/heroku cli, run `heroku login -i`
- Enter the mail id and **provide authoriation token as password.**

Answer (score 0):

I see your command is correct, but your syntax is incorrect. `heroku login -i` is the proper syntax. Between the login and -i, there should be a space between them. I have attached a screenshot with that as well. If you still encounter issues, please let me know.

[image: Screenshot attached for following commands]