# server error (500) after deploying to heroku - but only one page

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have recently deployed a project onto heroku using AWS for media and elephantsql.

Things seem to be working okay however there is only one page that returns a server 500 error.

Does anyone have any idea of where I can start to investigate?

I've tried moving the checkout page.

here is the page code i am trying to access

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load bag_tools %}

{% block extra_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'checkout/css/checkout.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block page_header %}
    <div class="container header-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="logo-font mb-4">Checkout</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-last mb-5">
                <p class="text-muted">Order Summary ({{ product_count }})</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-7 offset-2">
                        <p class="mb-1 mt-0 small text-muted">Item</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 text-right">
                        <p class="mb-1 mt-0 small text-muted">Subtotal</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% for item in bag_items %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2 mb-1">
                            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' item.product.id %}">
                                {% if item.product.image %}
                                    <img class="w-100" src="{{ item.product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                                {% else %}
                                    <img class="w-100" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}noimage.png" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                                {% endif %}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-7">
                            <p class="my-0"><strong>{{ item.product.name }}</strong></p>
                            <p class="my-0 small">Size: {% if item.product.has_sizes %}{{ item.size|upper }}{% else %}N/A{% endif %}</p>
                            <p class="my-0 small text-muted">Qty: {{ item.quantity }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 text-right">
                            <p class="my-0 small text-muted">${{ item.product.price | calc_subtotal:item.quantity }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <hr class="my-0">
                <div class="row text-black text-right">
                    <div class="col-7 offset-2">
                        <p class="my-0">Order Total:</p>
                        <p class="my-0">Delivery:</p>
                        <p class="my-0">Grand Total:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <p class="my-0">${{ total | floatformat:2 }}</p>
                        <p class="my-0">${{ delivery | floatformat:2 }}</p>
                        <p class="my-0"><strong>${{ grand_total | floatformat:2 }}</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                <p class="text-muted">Please fill out the form below to complete your order</p>
                <form action="{% url 'checkout' %}" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="rounded px-3 mb-5">
                        <legend class="fieldset-label small text-black px-2 w-auto">Details</legend>
                        {{ order_form.full_name | as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ order_form.email | as_crispy_field }}
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="rounded px-3 mb-5">
                        <legend class="fieldset-label small text-black px-2 w-auto">Delivery</legend>
                        {{ order_form.phone_number | as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ order_form.street_address1 | as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ order_form.street_address2 | as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ order_form.town_or_city | as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ order_form.county | as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ order_form.postcode | as_crispy_field }}
                        {{ order_form.country | as_crispy_field }}
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline float-right mr-0">
                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="id-save-info">Save this delivery information to my profile</label>
                                <input class="form-check-input ml-2 mr-0" type="checkbox" id="id-save-info" name="save-info" checked>
                            {% else %}
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="id-save-info">
                                    <a class="text-info" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Create an account</a> or 
                                    <a class="text-info" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">login</a> to save this information
                                </label>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="px-3">
                        <legend class="fieldset-label small text-black px-2 w-auto">Payment</legend>
                        <!-- A Stripe card element will go here -->
                        <div class="mb-3" id="card-element"></div>
                        <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                        <div class="mb-3 text-danger" id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                        <!-- Pass the client secret to the view so we can get the payment intent id -->
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ client_secret }}" name="client_secret">
                    </fieldset>

                    <div class="submit-button text-right mt-5 mb-2">                    
                        <a href="{% url 'view_bag' %}" class="btn btn-outline-black rounded-0">
                            <span class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="font-weight-bold">Adjust Bag</span>
                        </a>
                        <button id="submit-button" class="btn btn-black rounded-0">
                            <span class="font-weight-bold">Complete Order</span>
                            <span class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                        <p class="small text-danger my-0">
                            <span class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span>Your card will be charged <strong>${{ grand_total|floatformat:2 }}</strong></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="loading-overlay">
        <h1 class="text-light logo-font loading-spinner">
            <span class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-3x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i>
            </span>
        </h1>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block postloadjs %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {{ stripe_public_key|json_script:"id_stripe_public_key" }}
    {{ client_secret|json_script:"id_client_secret" }}
    <script src="{% static 'checkout/js/stripe_elements.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I've referenced the checkout page to other projects. I've checked the views.py and reviewed the settings.py and cannot seem to find any errors.

I've checked allowed hosts.

I have searched on google and stackoverflow but can't seem to find anyone with the error of just one page returning server 500 error.

here is the views of the page i am trying to access

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse, get_object_or_404, HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.contrib import messages
from django.conf import settings

from .forms import OrderForm
from .models import Order, OrderLineItem

from products.models import Product
from profiles.models import UserProfile
from profiles.forms import UserProfileForm
from bag.contexts import bag_contents

import stripe
import json


@require_POST
def cache_checkout_data(request):
    try:
        pid = request.POST.get('client_secret').split('_secret')[0]
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        stripe.PaymentIntent.modify(pid, metadata={
            'bag': json.dumps(request.session.get('bag', {})),
            'save_info': request.POST.get('save_info'),
            'username': request.user,
        })
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    except Exception as e:
        messages.error(request, 'Sorry, your payment cannot be \
            processed right now. Please try again later.')
        return HttpResponse(content=e, status=400)


def checkout(request):
    stripe_public_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
    stripe_secret_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    if request.method == 'POST':
        bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

        form_data = {
            'full_name': request.POST['full_name'],
            'email': request.POST['email'],
            'phone_number': request.POST['phone_number'],
            'country': request.POST['country'],
            'postcode': request.POST['postcode'],
            'town_or_city': request.POST['town_or_city'],
            'street_address1': request.POST['street_address1'],
            'street_address2': request.POST['street_address2'],
            'county': request.POST['county'],
        }

        order_form = OrderForm(form_data)
        if order_form.is_valid():
            order = order_form.save(commit=False)
            pid = request.POST.get('client_secret').split('_secret')[0]
            order.stripe_pid = pid
            order.original_bag = json.dumps(bag)
            order.save()
            for item_id, item_data in bag.items():
                try:
                    product = Product.objects.get(id=item_id)
                    if isinstance(item_data, int):
                        order_line_item = OrderLineItem(
                            order=order,
                            product=product,
                            quantity=item_data,
                        )
                        order_line_item.save()
                    else:
                        for size, quantity in item_data['items_by_size'].items():
                            order_line_item = OrderLineItem(
                                order=order,
                                product=product,
                                quantity=quantity,
                                product_size=size,
                            )
                            order_line_item.save()
                except Product.DoesNotExist:
                    messages.error(request, (
                        "One of the products in your bag wasn't found in our database. "
                        "Please call us for assistance!")
                    )
                    order.delete()
                    return redirect(reverse('view_bag'))

            # Save the info to the user's profile if all is well
            request.session['save_info'] = 'save-info' in request.POST
            return redirect(reverse('checkout_success', args=[order.order_number]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'There was an error with your form. \
                Please double check your information.')
    else:
        bag = request.session.get('bag', {})
        if not bag:
            messages.error(request, "There's nothing in your bag at the moment")
            return redirect(reverse('products'))

        current_bag = bag_contents(request)
        total = current_bag['grand_total']
        stripe_total = round(total * 100)
        stripe.api_key = stripe_secret_key
        intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=stripe_total,
            currency=settings.STRIPE_CURRENCY,
        )

        # Attempt to prefill the form with any info the user maintains in their profile
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                order_form = OrderForm(initial={
                    'full_name': profile.user.get_full_name(),
                    'email': profile.user.email,
                    'phone_number': profile.default_phone_number,
                    'country': profile.default_country,
                    'postcode': profile.default_postcode,
                    'town_or_city': profile.default_town_or_city,
                    'street_address1': profile.default_street_address1,
                    'street_address2': profile.default_street_address2,
                    'county': profile.default_county,
                })
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                order_form = OrderForm()
        else:
            order_form = OrderForm()

    if not stripe_public_key:
        messages.warning(request, 'Stripe public key is missing. \
            Did you forget to set it in your environment?')

    template = 'checkout/checkout.html'
    context = {
        'order_form': order_form,
        'stripe_public_key': stripe_public_key,
        'client_secret': intent.client_secret,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)


def checkout_success(request, order_number):
    """
    Handle successful checkouts
    """
    save_info = request.session.get('save_info')
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, order_number=order_number)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        # Attach the user's profile to the order
        order.user_profile = profile
        order.save()

        # Save the user's info
        if save_info:
            profile_data = {
                'default_phone_number': order.phone_number,
                'default_country': order.country,
                'default_postcode': order.postcode,
                'default_town_or_city': order.town_or_city,
                'default_street_address1': order.street_address1,
                'default_street_address2': order.street_address2,
                'default_county': order.county,
            }
            user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(profile_data, instance=profile)
            if user_profile_form.is_valid():
                user_profile_form.save()

    messages.success(request, f'Order successfully processed! \
        Your order number is {order_number}. A confirmation \
        email will be sent to {order.email}.')

    if 'bag' in request.session:
        del request.session['bag']

    template = 'checkout/checkout_success.html'
    context = {
        'order': order,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: 500 is a generic server error, most likely the page returning that status has a bug in it. It might be throwing an exception and django is automatically capturing the exception and sending a 500 response

Comment: I added my code to post i cant seem to find any errors. I even deleted the whole checkout html page to see if ther were any bugs but still g etting server error 500

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways to see the logs from your Heroku site.

if you have the heroku CLI installed, use

```
heroku logs --tail --app=<your-app-name>
```

Then hit your problem page again and you should get some logs.

I've also had good luck using the Papertrail add-on (I think there's a free tier) that gives you a longer window of logs, searching, filtering, etc.

Comment: hey thanks, I get a ip mismatch when i run that command

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error -- looks like there's a solution to that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363085/ip-address-mismatch-on-signing-into-heroku-cli (or just install Papertrail or similiar)